# Which element effects the positioning of my jquery drop-down menu --> making it go right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Since a while i am using a drop-down jquery check list. Though, for some styling purposes i want to make the list not drop down but rather have it fold/go to the right.

I try'd a couple of things (in my css) to accomplish this but nothing seems to work so far, i just cant find the right element that effects the menu dropping down. Or perhaps this is jquery handled but i cant really see the jquery doing that..

**This is the html of the drop-down list:**

```
<form method="post">
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select the country in which the event takes place</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Belgium" />Belgium</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Denmark" />Denmark</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="England" />England</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="France" />France</li>  
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Germany" />Germany</li>  
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Italy" />Italy</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Netherlands" />Netherlands</li>  
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Poland" />Poland</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Romania" />Romania</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Scotland" />Scotland</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Spain" />Spain</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Sweden" />Sweden</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_location[]" value="Other" />Other</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" id="select-all" value="Select/deselect all"/>Select/deselect all</li>  
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select type of Event</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Symposium" />Symposium</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Round table" />Round table</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Meeting" />Meeting</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Conference" />Conference</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Site visit" />Site visit</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Debate" />Debate</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_type[]" value="Other" />Other</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" id="select-all" value="Select/deselect all"/>Select/deselect all</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**This is the CSS of the drop-down list:**

```
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 20px 0px;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  color: #0094ff;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

**And this is the javascript/jquery code:**

```
 $('.select-all').click(function (event) {
    var $list = $(this).closest('.dropdown-check-list');
    $list.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('.dropdown-check-list .anchor').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-check-list').toggleClass("visible");
});
```

I also try'd to affect the rotate degrees in the css but this only affects the symbol (arrow).

I hope someone could point me in the right direction, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want your drop down to open to the right instead of straight to the center, to achieve this assign a margin to the ul and the dropdown window itself.

Ie:

```
.dropddownBox {
  margin-left: 50px; 
}
```

in your CSS will push the dropdown to the right for you. Same goes for the left, you can create a negative left margin to push it to the left if you want.

Edit:
I noticed it shoots down the dropdown menu and button included in the jsfiddle so I modified it a little to make sure it doesn't do that you can do this:

```
.dropddownBox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: 50px; 
}
```

I set the z-index just to make sure it shows up above other divs etc, if it does overlap.

Comment: Thank you a lot TimeDead! It works like a charm, well not 100% but at least i know now how i can do it and tweak it! Besides that, i now know how to use the z-index and what it is good for:)